# Get distance between top of scrollable parent and one of nested child nodes

Tags: javascript

I have vertically scrollable `<ul>` with several `<li>` in it.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item7</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    max-height: 50px;
}
li {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Then with JS I get `<ui>` and one of `<li>` nodes:

```
let ul = document.querySelector('ul')
let li = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(3)')
```

And I want to make function which gets ul and li nodes (something like `getDistance(ul, li)`) which returns distance between top of the ul and li in pixels. 
The question is how to make that function.

Comment: Why? For `nth-child(3)` it is probably 3 ?

Comment: `getDistance(ul, li)` is for getting distance in `pixel` or `percentage` ?

Comment: Distance in pixels.

Comment: [Hope this works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628644/9674579)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = /*your ul element*/
y = /*your li element*/
distX = y.offsetLeft - x.offsetLeft;
distY = y.offsetTop - x.offsetTop;
distance = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);
alert(Math.floor(distance));
```

but you have to substract first `x`'s height and width, if you put something inside. This method has some issues with support and border width of elements in different browsers.

Comment: If my answer works for you,  then please accept it and up vote it ;)